# Is there a complete list of what causes SqlPackage.exe to perform data motion (table recreation) when upgrading a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

When [generating a database upgrade using Sql Server Data Tools's sqlpackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh550080(vs.103).aspx#Anchor_7), it is possible that SSDT will generate code to migrate table data, this is, create a new temporary table with the desired final schema, move the data from the original table into the new table, drop the original table and then rename the temporary table to match the original table's name.

That code in the script can be found after the statement `PRINT N'Starting rebuilding table <tablename>';`.

I imagine most of the reasons for doing that is due to the fact that there is no atomic DDL statement to generate the change required by the upgrade. I found a [list](https://documentation.red-gate.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42534151) of such cases for another similar tool. However I am trying to find some documentation on when SSDT will perform data migration / table recreation, as I've seen some situations in which a DDL would be available to do the job, but SSDT would still do recreate the table (for instance, when altering a clustered index).

My question is: is there anywhere documented when SSDT will generate code for data migration/table recreation?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately that's not documented.  I had occasion to review the table data motion scenarios when implementing the ignore column order feature in SSDT. Even given the source code, it's difficult to produce a complete list of situations that result in table data motion, because it's treated as the "safe" fallback for unanticipated or otherwise unhandled situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for more control over how the data motion occurs, Flyway or Redgate Deploy might be a good option for you. Redgate Deploy differentiates from SSDT's state-based approach by generating the scripts up front and including these as the first class deployment artifacts in your visual studio project. This means you can review the scripts and, crucially, modify them, should you decide that it hasn't chosen the optimal approach.

More information about Redgate Deploy can be found [on the Redgate website](https://www.red-gate.com/products/redgate-deploy/).